# Use variable wrapped in squiggly brackets in array?

Tags: javascript

I've downloaded a plugin that does something like the following:

```
<span class="block block_{icon}"></span>
```

Where `{icon}` seems to be a variable's value (?).

How can I use `{icon}` as a key in an array, i.e. something like `array[{icon}]`?

Answer (score 0):

First if you want your key to be anything other than an Integer, you want a hash

```
var hash = new Hash()
// Or
var hash = {}

var array = new Array()
// Or
var array = []
```

Hashes will accept nearly anything as their key

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have much context, I'll show you how you might do it in pure JavaScript and you can tweak it to fit your exact needs:

```
<span class="block block_2"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

  var index = document
    .getElementsByTagName('span')[0]
    .classList[1]
    .split('_')[1];

  console.log(myArray[parseFloat(index)]);
</script>
```